# Why does the for loop produce output vertically?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am new to python and writing simple for loops

I am writing a program to remove the dashes from a telephone number input by the user.

```
phone =str(input("Enter a phone number")) #900-888-943
for i in phone:
    print(i.strip("-"))
```

However, the ouput I am receiving is:

```
9

0

0

8
```

> The output i desire is Number without dashes is 900888943.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is iterating over each character in the string. So you're essentially doing:

```
print("9".strip("-"))
print("0".strip("-"))
print("0".strip("-"))
print("-".strip("-"))
print("8".strip("-"))
print("8".strip("-"))
print("8".strip("-"))
print("-".strip("-"))
print("9".strip("-"))
print("4".strip("-"))
print("3".strip("-"))
```

In the cases where the string isn't `"-"`, `strip("-")` doesn't change anything, so it's just printing that string; when it's `"-"` it becomes an empty string, and it prints that.

By default, `print()` adds a newline after it prints the argument. You can use the optional `end=""` argument to change this.

```
phone =str(input("Enter a phone number")) #900-888-943
for i in phone:
    print(i.strip("-"), end="")
print("") # Add a newline at the end
```

But it would be simpler to just print `phone.replace('-', '')`, as in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, print ends each call with a new line. Also, your code will replace the dashes with empty spaces which it doesn't sound like you want.

What you can do instead is simply write the below:

`phone = str(input("Enter a phone number")).replace("-","")`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `str.replace`:

```
phone = str(input("Enter a phone number")) #900-888-943
print(phone.replace("-", ""))
# 900888943
```

If you want to use both `for` and `strip`, *list comprehension* is a good way to go:

```
phone = str(input("Enter a phone number")) #900-888-943
''.join([s.strip("-") for s in phone])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is calling the print at each time in the loop and thus printed a new line. You can try something like below:
You can do it in either way
Solution one: this will bring back the print to the same line

```
phone =str(input("Enter a phone number")) #900-888-943
for i in phone:
  print(i.strip("-"),end="")
```

Solution two: have a variable

```
phone =str(input("Enter a phone number")) #900-888-943
num = ""
for i in phone:
   num +=i

 print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
phone = '900-900-9000'

print(phone.replace('-','') //9009009000
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 provides the simplest solution, all you have to do is to provide one extra argument to the print function.

```
phone =str(input("Enter a phone number")) #900-888-943
for i in phone:
    print(i.replace('-',''),end="")
```

Now the Output will be:

```
900888943
```

And if for some other case, you need spaces in between each character all you have to do is to replace the end argument in print function from  `end=""` to `end=" "`

```
str="SomeData"
    for i in str:
        print(i,end=" ")
```

And Now the output will be:

```
S o m e D a t a
```